# Detecting visibility percentage of a UIView in iOS views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, intersection, overlap

I need to find out whether a target UIView object is visible on the screen. From my research, it looks like the consensus is to check if the `window` property of UIView object is the `keyWindow`. But this only partially solves my problem, because a view may be partially blocked by another view object on top of it. For example:

Half of the square in gray color is blocked by a rectangle in blue color, so the visibility of the gray square is 50% to the user.

[image: gray view is blocked partially by the blue view]

The solution I am working on is essentially following, but it does not work quite right:

1. Get the UIWindow object on the top:

```
    UIWindow *topWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult (UIWindow *win1, UIWindow *win2) {
    if (win1.windowLevel < win2.windowLevel) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if (win1.windowLevel > win2.windowLevel) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }] firstObject];
```

2. Then traverse all the subviews of the `topWindow` and find all the subviews after my target view object:
3. Convert the frame of targetView and all the subviews after it to the coordinates of `topWindow`, for detecting if there's intersection.

```
NSMutableArray *stack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:topWindow.subviews];
UIView *targetView = nil;
NSInteger targetViewTag = 10;
NSMutableArray *postViews = [NSMutableArray array]; // views detected after targetView, used for detection overlap with targetView

while ([stack count] > 0) {
            UIView *curr = [stack lastObject];
            [stack removeObject:curr];

            if (curr.isHidden || curr.window == nil) {
                continue;
            }

            if (curr.tag == targetViewTag) {
                targetView = curr;
            } else if (targetView) {
                [postViews addObject:curr];
            }

            for (UIView *sub in [curr subviews]) {
              [stack addObject:sub];
            }
        }

    // if targetView is found:
    if (targetView) {
      float visiblePercentage = 100;

      for (UIView *pw in postViews) {
                    // convert frames to topWindow for detecting intersection
                    CGRect swFrame = [targetView convertRect:targetView.frame toView:topWindow];
                    CGRect pwFrame = [pw convertRect:pw.frame toView:topWindow];
                    
                    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(swFrame, pwFrame)) {
                        CGRect intersection = CGRectIntersection(swFrame, pwFrame);

                        CGFloat intersectArea = intersection.size.width * intersection.size.height;
                        CGFloat swArea = swFrame.size.width * swFrame.size.height;
                        // update visiblePercentage
                        visiblePercentage = visiblePercentage - (100 * intersectArea / swArea);
                    }
                }

   }
```

I am not sure if it's a good idea to convert the frames for views in different subviews to the `topWindow` coordinate, but the `visiblePercentage` does not look right, as it gives me negative number. Anyone has better way of calculating the visible percentage for partially/entirely blocked views? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having spent more time on my algorithm, I finally realized why it did not work for me, because the way for traversing the view hierarchy with the `stack` data structure would make the `blocking views` pop out of the stack sooner than `targetView`. So after making the change in the following line, the calculation for visibility percentage works for me:

```
while ([stack count] > 0) {
            UIView *curr = [stack lastObject];
            [stack removeObject:curr];

            if (curr.isHidden || curr.window == nil) {
                continue;
            }

            if (curr.tag == targetViewTag) {
                targetView = curr;
            } else if (targetView == nil) { // NOTE: correct this line from else if (targetView)
                [postViews addObject:curr];
            }

            for (UIView *sub in [curr subviews]) {
              [stack addObject:sub];
            }
        }
```

The stack data structure pops out those views on top of my `targetView` first, which is the trick for fixing my problem. Thanks for looking anyway :)